# Forward declaration of class used in template function is not compiled by clang++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, forward-declaration, clang++

There is this code:

```
class A;

template <class T>
void fun() {
   A a;
}

class A { 
public: 
   A() {  } 
};

int main() { 
   fun<int>(); 
   return 0;
}
```

g++ 4.5 and g++ 4.7 compiles this without error. But clang++ 3.2 (trunk) gives this error:

```
main.cpp:5:6: error: variable has incomplete type 'A'
   A a;
     ^
main.cpp:1:7: note: forward declaration of 'A'
class A;
      ^
```

Which compiler is right then according to C++ standard?

Comment: Since you try to create a object of type `A` the compiler has to know its size which it cannot know without having seen the full definition, so clang would be right here (but I don't have the std reference).

Comment: Is there any switch provided by clang to compile such a code?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Which compiler is right then according to C++ standard?

Both are correct. This is an ill-formed program. Emphasis mine:

> N3290 14.6¶9
>   If a type used in a non-dependent name is incomplete at the point at which a template is defined but is complete at the point at which an instantiation is done, and if the completeness of that type affects whether or not the program is well-formed or affects the semantics of the program, **the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required**.

That clang++ and other compilers do issue a diagnostic here is a nice-to-have added feature, but a diagnosis is not mandatory. That clause "the program is ill-formed; no diagnostic is required" gives a compiler developer free reign to do just about anything in such circumstances and still be compliant.

Comment: why then programmer isn't even informed by g++ that something is wrong? should it be so that both compilers are correct but one does his job and the second does something very different?

Comment: The intent is to allow lazy template processing. The standard allows implementations to defer detailed parsing to the point at which a template is instantiated. Class `A` is known at the point of instantiation, so it compiles. It's still ill-formed because another file could `#include` your template definition, define a completely different class `A`, and create a different `fun<int>()`. This would fail to link because it violates the one definition rule (even if you qualified `fun` as `inline`).

Answer (score 5):

Clang is correct, as far as I know. At your function fun, you do not know the size of A, and since your allocating an A, you need to know it's size. In my opinion, gcc is way to forgiving here.

Comment: clang is being nice by detecting the problem, but gcc's lack of a diagnosis is also correct. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

`clang++` is using the correct behavior, this is described in section `4.6/9` of the standard (*n1905*).

---

> **`Templates  14.6/9  Name resolution`**
>
> If a name does not depend on a template-parameter (as defined in
>   *14.6.2*), a declaration (or set of declarations) for that name shall be in scope at the point where the name appears in the template
>   definition; the name is bound to the declaration (or declarations)
>   found at that point and this binding is not affected by declarations
>   that are visible at the point of instantiation.

---

To put things in simpler terms; if the name is **not** dependent on a template-parameter it should be in scope where the definition is found; therefore you'll need to define `A` before your definition of `template<typename T> void fun ()`.

Comment: N1905 is a bit old. It's from 2005. N3291 was (I think) the final draft.

Answer (score 0):

Comeau's compiler does not like it either:

```
"ComeauTest.c", line 5: error: incomplete type is not allowed
     A a;
       ^
```

However my attempts at finding chapter and verse in the C++ standard were fruitless. It seems hidden in between the lines and interactions of "point of instantiation", "name resolution". Paragraphs 14.6/8 and 14.6/9 of the 2003 standard seem relevant.

Comment: i dont have the spec at hand, but i know that a rule was added (as a DR resolution) to render his code "illformed; no diagnostic required" sometime after c++98 or c++03. it is located in the paragraph that talks about illformed template definitions.