# apache ignite 2.0 c++ on osx does not compile

Tags: c++, macos, ignite

I tried to compile Apache Ignite 2.0 C++. I am running make from the directory `/opt/apache-ignite-2.0.0-src/modules/platforms/cpp`. I already compiled all Java code and I can start Apache Ignite just fine. However, C++ does not compile. It seems like I have to go through C++ code to fix the problem.

The error I get when running make is:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make  all-recursive
Making all in common
Making all in include
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making all in os/linux/include
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
Making all in binary
Making all in include
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
  CXX      src/binary/binary_containers.lo
In file included from src/binary/binary_containers.cpp:18:
In file included from ./include/ignite/binary/binary_containers.h:30:
In file included from ./include/ignite/impl/binary/binary_writer_impl.h:35:
In file included from ./include/ignite/impl/binary/binary_object_impl.h:31:

./include/ignite/impl/binary/binary_reader_impl.h:986:58: error: variable has incomplete type 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
                            ignite::binary::BinaryReader reader(&readerImpl);
                                                         ^
./include/ignite/binary/binary_type.h:135:15: note: forward declaration of 'ignite::binary::BinaryReader'
        class BinaryReader;
          ^
In file included from src/binary/binary_containers.cpp:18:
In file included from ./include/ignite/binary/binary_containers.h:30:
./include/ignite/impl/binary/binary_writer_impl.h:702:54: error: variable has incomplete type 'ignite::binary::BinaryWriter'
                        ignite::binary::BinaryWriter writer(&writerImpl);
                                                     ^
./include/ignite/binary/binary_type.h:134:15: note: forward declaration of 'ignite::binary::BinaryWriter'
        class BinaryWriter;
          ^
2 errors generated.
make[3]: *** [src/binary/binary_containers.lo] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, OS X is [not supported](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/getting-started-1) officially. You may want to write to [Apache Ignite user mailing list](http://apache-ignite-users.70518.x6.nabble.com) to ask someone to help you. Make sure you subscribe before sending your question though, so everyone will see your mail.

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you are using clang++ to compile ignite.

The reason itself is explained
[in a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10993720/forward-declaration-of-class-used-in-template-function-is-not-compiled-by-clang): the Apache Ignite C++ code is wrong (it has a bug), but it so happens that some compilers do not detect and report the problem.

One solution (beside modifying ignite source code) would be to use g++. Instruction for OSX are [in a different SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2122425/how-do-i-install-g-on-macos-x).